# Can't run GTK with GR plot

Tags: julia, gtk, gr

I'm trying to run a GR plot in a GTK Window.  The example code is here https://github.com/jheinen/GR.jl/blob/master/examples/gtk_ex.jl  My system is a MacBook Pro M1.

I get an error that:

```
julia> FATAL ERROR: Gtk state corrupted by error thrown in a callback:
ERROR: could not load library "libGR.so"
dlopen(libGR.so.dylib, 0x0001): tried: '/Applications/Julia-1.7.app/Contents/Resources/julia/lib/julia/libGR.so.dylib' (no such file), '/Applications/Julia-1.7.app/Contents/Resources/julia/bin/../lib/libGR.so.dylib' (no such file), 'libGR.so.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/local/lib/libGR.so.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libGR.so.dylib' (no such file), '/Users/bryan/src/tibra/Tibra.jl/libGR.so.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/local/lib/libGR.so.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libGR.so.dylib' (no such file)
```

Comment: Are you using Julia via the ARM binary or the x86 binary? If the former, you might try instead the latter via rosetta and see if the error persists.

Comment: @cbk That didnt work.  Same error.

Comment: Looks like something went wrong in your GR installation, can you try `] build GR`?